Trying to access array offset on value of type null when i try to reset my password using email
I'm getting this error when I try to reset my password using email. I already my composer.But still  it's same.
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string ...$guards): Response
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}


$guards is potentially empty that is why NULL is assigned and in turn you are getting this error,


Check the Reset Password View
Ensure that the view responsible for the password reset form is correctly set up. This form should have inputs for email, token, password, and password_confirmation.

Check the Password Reset Routes
Verify that you have defined the correct routes for password resets in routes/web.php or routes/api.php, such as:


Route::post('password/email', [PasswordResetController::class, 'sendResetLinkEmail']);
Route::post('password/reset', [PasswordResetController::class, 'reset']);


Check for Null Values
The error could be due to a null value being accessed in your controller or middleware. In your PasswordResetController or any related middleware, make sure that you handle null values properly. For instance, if you're trying to access an array or object, first check if it exists:

if (isset($array['key'])) {
    $value = $array['key'];
} else {
    $value = null; // Handle the null case accordingly
}

